# How to create an anchor by group in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, anchor

I'm making a scaffold like an dictionnary.
I filtered the definitions by group of letters and alphabetical order.
The actual page is here https://emangaka.herokuapp.com/definitions
I would like link each letter from left column to the corresponding group.
You know, when we click a letter we redirected directly on the top of the correspondig group.

My current controller is

```
  def index
    @definitions = Definition.all.order('title ASC').group_by{|d| d.title[0]}
    @titre = "Définitions"
  end
```

And the view index is

```
<% @definitions.each do |letter, definition| %>
  <h2><%= letter %></h2>
  <% definition.each do |defn| %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<p><%= defn.title.downcase + "　" + defn.japonais.downcase  %></p>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<p><%= defn.content.html_safe %></p>
</div>
</div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And I would link that or another way

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div><span class="tag"><a href="#">Top</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">A</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">B</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">C</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">D</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">E</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">F</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">G</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">H</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">I</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">J</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">K</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">L</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">M</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">N</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">O</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">P</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">Q</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">R</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">S</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">T</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">U</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">V</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">W</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">X</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">Y</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#">Z</a></span>
</div>
```

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html anchors

```
<span class="tag"><a href="#a">A</a></span>
<span class="tag"><a href="#b">B</a></span>
```

Add `a` tag with an anchor

```
<% @definitions.each do |letter, definition| %>
  <a id="<%= letter.downcase %>"></a>
  <h2><%= letter %></h2>
  <% definition.each do |defn| %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
```